# Python SSL server gives me "501 Unsupported method GET"

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplehttpserver

I've followed [this link](https://anvileight.com/blog/2016/03/20/simple-http-server-with-python/) to build a simple file server with SSL.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

# openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, keyfile="key.pem", certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

I have created a certificate successfully, `key.pem` and `cert.pem` file paths are cool and I can start the server using `python server.py`. I am asked for a password, enter it, then it freezes for a bit and then it seems to run.

However, when I enter some URL such as `https://localhost:4443/index.html` I get **500 Unsupported method GET. Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.** Do I need to do something more to make my server serve the current directory? Until now I have just used `python -m http.server 8000` (`SimpleHTTPServer` when on Mac.) I am using Python 3.

This is an will stay local so don't worry about the `PEM` files and the server script being exposed through it (if it worked!). I am also okay with the certificate being untrusted and instructed Chrome to visit the page anyway. I just need it to allow me to access camera without having to deploy my app somewhere with a legit cert.

Comment: The link contains code that is not legit, for python3. What you want is the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler and you try to use the BaseHTTPRequestHandler, so maybe it's a bogus article, and not that simple as the author claims. Tried and make it work but it didn't work for python 2 or 3 following the link. DIY!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server):

> class http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler(request, client_address, server)
>
> > This class is used to handle the HTTP requests that arrive at the server. By itself, it cannot respond to any actual HTTP requests; it must be subclassed to handle each request method (e.g. GET or POST).

Try using [SimpleHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) instead, eg,

```
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
```